# How to detect end points in a binarize picture

Tags: image-processing

There is a picture:

[image]

When I try to use `MorphologicalTransform` to detect the end points

```
pic = Thinning@Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8dm3.png"];
MorphologicalTransform[pic, "EndPoints"]
```

[image]

It will detect five points.But four point is expected.So I wanna find it out like this,but I get nothing

```
ImageFilter[If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &, pic, 1]
```

[image]

Confuse me.But as my comprehension to `ImageFilter`, I think my code is right.If I wanna use `ImageFilter` to implement it,how to improve my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

In this particular case it is quite sufficient just to apply `Pruning` with `1` as the second argument:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8dm3.png"];
ep = MorphologicalTransform[Pruning[Thinning@Binarize@i, 1], "EndPoints"];
PixelValuePositions[%, White]
```

> ```
> {{271, 546}, {190, 471}, {694, 382}, {899, 366}}
> ```

The purpose of `Pruning` is to remove just one pixel which causes additional end point caught by `"EndPoints"`:

```
PixelValuePositions[
 ImageDifference[Thinning@Binarize@i, Pruning[Thinning@Binarize@i, 1]], White]
```

> ```
> {{357, 341}}
> ```

---

### Original answer

One approach is to apply `Pruning` and then take `"SkeletonEndPoints"`:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8dm3.png"];
ep1 = MorphologicalTransform[Pruning[Thinning@Binarize@i, 150], "SkeletonEndPoints"]
```

> [image]

```
PixelValuePositions[%, White]

{{271, 546}, {190, 471}, {694, 382}, {899, 366}}
```

In this particular case we can make `Pruning` much more efficient if we apply `FillingTransform` before `Thinning`:

```
ep2 = MorphologicalTransform[
 Pruning[Thinning@Binarize@FillingTransform@i, 4], "SkeletonEndPoints"];

ep1 == ep2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Now we can ensure that we actually have found end points of the thinned image:

```
ppos = ImageValuePositions[ep2, White]
```

> ```
> {{270.5, 545.5}, {189.5, 470.5}, {693.5, 381.5}, {898.5, 365.5}}
> ```

```
pic = Thinning@Binarize@i;
Show[ImageTrim[pic, {#}, 1], GridLines -> {Range[10], Range[10]}, ImageSize -> 100, 
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}] & /@ ppos
```

> [image: image list]

We can check what these pixels correspond to in the original image:

```
Show[ImageTrim[ReplaceImageValue[i, # -> Red], {#}, 5], 
   GridLines -> {Range[10], Range[10]}, ImageSize -> 100, 
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}] & /@ ppos
```

> [image: image list]

Comment: I'm really don't know what the `Pruning` do.But it will lead to a right result. Can you give a explaination?

Comment: @yode Citing [the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pruning.html), "`Pruning[image,n]` removes branches that are at most *n* pixels long." In the other words, it computes lengths of branches of the skeleton an then "eats up" all branches with length no longer than *n* pixels. There is no explicit definition for the "length" but the principle seems to be clear.

Comment: Actually I know its usage,but I don't know its function in here.No branch be removed in here I think or I miss other something.We can [show the result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hnv2Z.jpg) of `Pruning`.

Comment: Oh.I just mean you first solution here `ep1 = MorphologicalTransform[Pruning[Thinning@Binarize@i, 150], "SkeletonEndPoints"]`.In the second solution its behavior in our expectation.

Comment: @yode `Pruning` here removes a tiny branch (which is the source of the trouble). In the case of `ep1` this "branch" is of length one pixel as you can see with `ImageDifference[Thinning@Binarize@i, Pruning[Thinning@Binarize@i, 150]]`, but without `Pruning` we get this pixel as one of the end points even with `"SkeletonEndPoints"` (check `MorphologicalTransform[Thinning@Binarize@i, "SkeletonEndPoints"]`).

Comment: @yode I just have found that `MorphologicalTransform[Pruning[Thinning@Binarize@i, 1], "EndPoints"]` is actually quite sufficient. I'll update the answer with this (much more efficient) solution.

Comment: Thanks for your `ImageDifference`.If not,I have to find a high magnification.:)

Answer (score 3):

[As Alexey noted in his follow-up question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110633/2305), there appears to be a bug with range-1 filters on binarised images. That means your original code actually was supposed to work. You can indeed fix it by "unbinarising" the image first:

```
pic = Thinning@Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8dm3.png"];
nonBinaryPic = Image[pic, "Real"];

filtered = ImageFilter[If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &, nonBinaryPic, 1];
Total[ImageData@filtered, 2]
(* 4. *)
```

You might have to re-binarise `filtered` after the computation if you want to end up with a binarised image.

Of course this workaround is somewhat unsatisfactory, but at least it lets you use your original approach, which I'd personally prefer to using a similar approach on the binarised image when it's not even clear why the bug exists in the first place.

Comment: (+1) You can convert binary image to grayscale simply with `Image[pic, "Real"]` or `Image[pic, "Real32"]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ah, thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

By increasing the radius in your `ImageFilter` from 1 to 2, I'm able to pick up the endpoints via (with Alexey Popkov's help),

```
ImageFilter[If[#[[3, 3]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 3, 1, 0] &, pic, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking your approach gives not the end pixels but next-to-end pixels as you can see with `ppos=ImageValuePositions[ImageFilter[If[(#[[2,2]]==1||#[[-2,-2]]==1)&&Total[#,2]==2,1,0]&,pic,2],White];
Show[ImageTrim[pic,{#},2],GridLines->{Range[10],Range[10]},ImageSize->100,Method->{"GridLinesInFront"->True}]&/@ppos` ([output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DxyW8.png)).

Comment: Thank you.  I assumed there was a better way to get this, but from the OP I took it they want an answer that uses `ImageFilter` so I just fiddled with it until it gave the apparently right points.

Comment: Can you explain why the OP's `ImageFilter` approach doesn't work? I seem to understand how your method work but still don't see why it shouldn't work with radius `1`.

Comment: For obtaining the correct end points one can use `ImageFilter[If[(#[[3,3]]==1||#[[-3,-3]]==1)&&Total[#,2]==3,1,0]&,pic,2]`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Actually, with that fix you don't need the `Or` or the second condition there.   But for the life of me I can't see why `ImageFilter[If[#[[3, 3]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 3, 1, 0] &, pic, 2]` works when `ImageFilter[If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &, pic, 1]` fails.  I put a `Print[MatrixForm@#];` statement in the first and it looks like the second form should work also.

Comment: I have created [separate question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110633/280) on this issue.

Comment: We cannot find [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b9ruP.png) end points when the radius is 2 and total is 3.

Comment: @yode - but you wouldn't find that point if the radius was 1 and the total was 2 either....

Comment: @JasonB Ok.Sounds reasonable.Thinks for your interesting solution.

Answer (score 2):

Imperfect Branch points often are being caught as `"EndPoints"`. You may filter them out like this:

```
i   = Thinning@Binarize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8dm3.png";
iep = ImageMultiply[
      ColorNegate@ Dilation[MorphologicalTransform[i, "SkeletonBranchPoints"], 15], 
      MorphologicalTransform[i, "EndPoints"]], 5];

Dilation[iep, 5] (*for visualization *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It is certainly a solution by branch points to filter it.But I just don't really like the 15.I think it will result a inaccurate result in some case,such as thebranch points  near to the end points.But I don't very affirm my guess.