# Why does ImageFilter fail with radius 1, but works with radius 2?

Tags: bugs, image-processing, backslide

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 13.1.0** [CASE:3968469]

---

When thinking on a way to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110610/280) using `ImageFilter` I have found (with  [Jason B](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9490/jason-b)'s help) that we can find the end points of the skeleton by increasing the radius in `ImageFilter` from `1` to `2` in the following way:

```
pic = Thinning@Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8dm3.png"];
ep2 = ImageFilter[If[#[[3, 3]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 3, 1, 0] &, pic, 2];
ppos = PixelValuePositions[ep2, White]
```

> ```
> {{271, 546}, {190, 471}, {694, 382}, {899, 366}}
> ```

But I cannot figure out why the original approach with radius `1` fails:

```
ep1 = ImageFilter[If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &, pic, 1];
PixelValuePositions[ep1, White]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

This looks unexpected because there is no actual difference between these two approaches as can be clearly seen by visualizing the neighborhood pixels in the thinned image:

```
ArrayPlot[1 - ImageData[ImageTrim[pic, {# - .5}, 2]], Mesh -> True, 
   ImageSize -> 100] & /@ ppos
```

> [image: output]

Can anyone explain this issue? Is it a bug?

---

#### UPDATE: Additional observations

With the [help by Martin Büttner](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110633/why-imagefilter-fails-with-radius-1-while-works-with-radius-2#comment300099_110633) I have discovered that in this particular case **the filter function is always supplied with zeros when the radius is `1`**. Even weirder, there are only 76 (!) evaluations of the filter function:

```
n = 0; count = 0;

ImageFilter[If[Total[#, 2] == 0, ++n; 0, ++n; ++count; 1] &, pic, 1];

{n, count}
```

> ```
> {76, 0}
> ```

---

All the above output was obtained with version 10.4. With version 8.0.4 `ImageFilter` behaves as expected:

```
pic = Thinning@Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8dm3.png"];
ep1 = ImageFilter[If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &, pic, 1];
Total[ImageData[ep1], 2]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

So this seems to be a regression bug.

<sub>Reported as [CASE:3968469]</sub>

Comment: I was quite baffled by this as well when trying to answer the other question. It seems that a radius of `1` on a `Binarize`d image always supplies the filter function with zeroes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be quite the truth. The first input to the filter function can be non-zero, but all the ones afterwards seem to be zero. Tested with: `img = Binarize@RandomImage[1, {10, 10}]; ImageFilter[(Print@#; 1) &, img, 1]`

Comment: Obviously: `76 == 42 + 34` as expected :)

Comment: As further proof that the issue is the `ImageType` (`Bit`), [it's possible to work around the issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110635/2305) by "unbinarising" the image with `Image@N@ImageData@...` (although I wonder if there isn't a simpler way to convert image types?).

Comment: @Dr.belisarius :). Have you checked it with version 9? I have found that the issue isn't present in version 8.0.4.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov On v9 the result is the same as in the OP

Comment: I'm a lot of pressure to understand your English.

Comment: The 76 evaluations might be explained by some kind of parallel (nonatomic) writing operations in the variable n during filter evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can use `MorphologicalTransform[image,f]` for filtering binary images using 3×3 pixels window:

```
ep2 = MorphologicalTransform[pic, If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &];
ppos = PixelValuePositions[ep2, White]
```

> ```
> {{271, 546}, {190, 471}, {694, 382}, {899, 366}}
> ```

This method is **2 times faster** than the non-buggy `ImageFilter`, here are timings for *Mathematica* 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64:

```
Do[i1 = ImageFilter[If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &, pic, 1], {10}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Do[i2 = MorphologicalTransform[pic, If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &], {10}]; // AbsoluteTiming 

i1 == i2
```

> ```
> {0.7150409, Null}
>
> {0.3280187, Null}
>
> True
> ```

It is also much faster than alternative workarounds listed below and in the original question.

---

Another way is to use `ArrayFilter` instead of `ImageFilter`:

```
ep3 = Image@
  ArrayFilter[If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &, ImageData[pic], {1, 1}]
ppos3 = PixelValuePositions[ep2, White]
```

> [image]
>
> ```
> {{271, 546}, {190, 471}, {694, 382}, {899, 366}}
> ```

```
ImageData[ep3] == ImageData@ep2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

... or to use `BlockMap` along with `ArrayPad`:

```
ep4 = Image@
  BlockMap[If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 2, 1, 0] &, 
   ArrayPad[ImageData[pic], 1, "Fixed"], {3, 3}, 1]
ppos4 = PixelValuePositions[ep2, White]
```