# How to implement Controls for operations on an image with this scheme?

Tags: image-processing, functional-style, gui-construction

This post is somewhat connected to my past post "[how to get a deformable mesh from this binarized image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129011/how-to-get-a-deformable-mesh-from-this-binarized-image?noredirect=1&lq=1)" although not quite important for what I intend to ask here.

I have an image of an animal tissue and have done some segmentation procedure on the image to get a mask (kindly see below):

image of cell

[image]

mask after segmentation

[image]

`Highlighted[img,imgmask]` shows that the segmentation is not good enough.

[image]

Since the segmentation is imperfect, I have devised a crude strategy to "delete edges" where incorrect segmentation occurs and furthermore, "add edges" where segmentation does not result in a boundary.

I have tweaked the code from my previous post and am posting it here so that both functions yield a  mask at the end with an added or removed edge.

**Edge Removal**

```
(* function for removing edges *)
deleteEdgeSegments[origimage_, initmask_, selectedpts_,
color_: RGBColor[0.2, 0.5, 0.9]] := 
Module[{pts = selectedpts, original = origimage, mask = initmask },

pts = Map[FromDigits, pts, {2}];
mask = DeleteSmallComponents[ReplacePixelValue[mask, pts -> 0]];

If[False,Print@GraphicsRow[{HighlightImage[
HighlightImage[original, initmask], {color,
AbsolutePointSize[10], Point@pts}], 
HighlightImage[original, mask]}, ImageSize -> Full]];

Return@mask;]
```

similarly the function for adding edges is given below:

**Edge Addition**

```
(* code for edge addition *)
interpPoints[selectedpts_, interpthresh_] := Module[{pts = selectedpts,
ptsToChange, positionReversal,reverselist, xrange, yrange, xs, ys,
ascendListOrder, interpolatedList, threshold = interpthresh},

pts = Map[FromDigits, pts, {2}];
pts = Partition[pts, 2, 1];
positionReversal = Position[pts, {{x_, _}, {x_, _}}];
reverselist = pts /. t : {{x_, _}, {x_, _}} :> Reverse /@ t;
ascendListOrder = Map[SortBy[#, First] &, reverselist];

interpolatedList = Map[Function[{x},
xs = x[[All, 1]];
ys = x[[All, 2]];

xrange = Range[Sequence @@ xs, threshold];
yrange = Subdivide[Sequence @@ ys, Length[xrange] - 1];
ptsToChange = Thread@{xrange, yrange}], ascendListOrder] // Round;

Flatten[MapAt[Map[Reverse, #] &, interpolatedList, positionReversal], 1]
]
```

Now I wish to implement a Controls related scheme to integrate the disjointed pieces of code together.

Specifically, I wish to import an image and its associated mask so that a user may perform an "Edge Deletion" and "Edge Addition" operations on the mask - with a list of points selected using `MousePosition` from `HighlightedImage[image,mask]`.

If the mask comes out to be incorrect/defective (checked by `HighlightedImage[image,newmask]`) after a single operation (add or delete edge) then the user can undo the change on the mask i.e. the old mask stays. However, if the resulting mask is reasonable after the operation the user can replace the `old mask` with the `newmask`.

The user can do operations for as many times as necessary to get a `mask` that fits correctly when superimposed on the image.

The question is how to implement such a `Control` for the process. I have not worked with Controls before.

I am pasting a schematic that I have drawn to elucidate the process.

[image]

Comment: thanks for notifying me. I upvoted all the answers to all the previous questions. Sorry i am relatively a newcomer so did not have an idea about accepting answer. I did that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been working on the problem for some days and came up with a naive/modest strategy to the answer. I am new to `DynamicModule` so it may not be the perfect solution, however the current code has all the functionality that I desire. The current code is posted below the bold heading titled **code for implementing control**

There is one problem I want someone to help me with and for that you have my infinite gratitude. **the function `zoomMask` is somewhat slow and moreover, one has to move the mouse very subtly**.
The function basically enables the user to zoom into the mask (red lines) and select the right pixels for **edge deletion** or **edge addition**.
Currently the function uses `HighlightImage` to superimpose the `MousePosition` on the imagemask. Is there a way to make it faster? Kindly check the image on the right of `pixel val -> 0` which delineates the result of `zoomMask` and the associated code below.

the code can be run by `correctSegmentation[image, corresponding mask,"some path to save"]`

[image]

**implementing Control (new code)**

```
correctSegmentation[image_?ImageQ, correspondingMask_?ImageQ, saveDir_?StringQ] := 

Module[{img = image, imgmask = correspondingMask, saveLink = saveDir},

DynamicModule[{list = {}, temp, mouse, mask = imgmask, 
reset = imgmask, (placeholder = 
  HighlightImage[img, Dynamic@mask]), boxwidth = 10, 
interp = 0.07, magmask = 5, rule, undo = imgmask, magimage = 10, 
save},

Framed[Column@{EventHandler[
   Column[{Row@{Magnify[Dynamic@placeholder, magimage],
       Manipulate[
        If[temp =!= None,
         Row@{               
           Style["pixel val" -> PixelValue[mask, Round@temp], 
            Bold, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
           zoomMask[
            Sequence @@ Flatten@{temp, mask, boxwidth, magmask}]
           }, "Magnify Mask"
         ], {pt, Dynamic[temp = MousePosition["Graphics"]], 
         Locator, Appearance -> None}]
       }, Dynamic@list}],

   {"MouseClicked", 
     1} :> (list = 
      If[(mouse = MousePosition["Graphics"]) =!= None , 
       AppendTo[list, mouse], list])],

  ButtonBar[{
    "Delete Edge" :> 
     If[Length@list > 0, (undo = mask; 
       mask = deleteEdgeSegments[mask, list]; list = {};)],
    "Add Edge" :> 
     If[Length@list > 0, (undo = mask; 
       mask = ReplacePixelValue[mask, 
           interpPoints[list, interp] -> 1] // Pruning // 
         Thinning; list = {};)],
    "Undo Operation" :> (mask = undo; list = {};),
    "Reset Mask" :> (mask = reset; list = {}; undo = mask),
    "Show/Hide points" :> 
     If[Length@list > 
       0, (placeholder = 
        placeholder /. {(rule = 
            HighlightImage[img, Dynamic@mask] -> 
             HighlightImage[
              HighlightImage[img, 
               Dynamic@mask], {RGBColor[0.2, 0.6, 0.9], 
               AbsolutePointSize[1], Point@list}]), 
          Reverse@rule})],
    "Reset points" :> (list = {};),
    "Save" :> (Export[saveLink, mask]; list = {};)
    }, Background -> LightBlue, ImageMargins -> 5]
  }, Background -> LightGray]
]
]
```

below is the code for `zoomMask` which is called in the **GUI Code**

**zoomMask code**

```
zoomMask := Function[{x, y, image, width, magnifymask},

Module[{row1, row2, col1, col2, imagedim = ImageDimensions[image]},

CompoundExpression[
If[imagedim[[2]] - y - width <= 0, row1 = 0, 
 row1 = imagedim[[2]] - y - width]; 
If[imagedim[[2]] - y + width >= imagedim[[2]], 
 row2 = imagedim[[2]], row2 = imagedim[[2]] - y + width]; 
If[x - width <= 0, col1 = 0, col1 = x - width];
If[x + width >= imagedim[[1]], col2 = imagedim[[1]], 
 col2 = x + width];
Magnify[ImageTake[HighlightImage[image, {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3], 
    Graphics@Point[Round@{x, y} - 1]}], {row1, row2},{col1,col2}],magnifymask]]
]
]
```

the other two functions are `deleteEdgeSegments` and `interpPoints`. The two codes are slightly modified from the ones posted in the question.

**deleteEdgeSegments code (for deleting edges)**

```
deleteEdgeSegments[initmask_, selectedpts_] :=
Module[{pts = selectedpts, mask = initmask, whitepixpos, nearest},

whitepixpos = PixelValuePositions[mask, 1];

nearest = Nearest[whitepixpos, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];

pts = pts /. patt : {_, _} /; ! MemberQ[whitepixpos, patt] :>(nearest[patt])/. 
x : {{_Integer, _Integer}} :> First@x ;

mask = DeleteSmallComponents[ReplacePixelValue[mask, pts -> 0]];
Return@mask;
] /; Length@selectedpts > 0;
```

**interpPoints code (used for adding edges)**

```
interpPoints[selectedpts_, initmask_, interpthresh_] := 
Module[{pts = selectedpts, ptsToChange, positionReversal, 
 reverselist, xrange, yrange, xs, ys, ascendListOrder, 
 interpolatedList, threshold = interpthresh, whitepixpos, nearest,
  extractends, mask = initmask},

whitepixpos = PixelValuePositions[mask, 1];
nearest = Nearest[whitepixpos, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
extractends = {First@pts, Last@pts};

MapThread[
 Replace[extractends[[#1]], 
   x_ /; ! MemberQ[whitepixpos, x] :> (#2[pts, 
      First@nearest[x]])] &, {{1, 2}, {PrependTo, AppendTo}}]; 

pts = Partition[DeleteDuplicates@pts, 2, 1];
positionReversal = Position[pts, {{x_, _}, {x_, _}}];
reverselist = pts /. t : {{x_, _}, {x_, _}} :> Reverse /@ t;  
ascendListOrder = Map[SortBy[#, First] &, reverselist];

interpolatedList = Map[Function[{x},
    xs = x[[All, 1]];
    ys = x[[All, 2]];

    xrange = Range[Sequence @@ xs, threshold];
    yrange = Subdivide[Sequence @@ ys, Length[xrange] - 1];

    ptsToChange = Thread@{xrange, yrange}
    ], ascendListOrder] // Round;

DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[MapAt[Map[Reverse, #] &, interpolatedList,positionReversal], 1]

] /; Length@selectedpts > 0;
```