# Is it possible to extract vertices and lines from this image?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I have the following image

[image]

Is it possible to extract the lines from this image and then convert those lines to a graph representation? I tried using `ImagesLines[]` with `Binarize[]` but got very bad results.

Comment: Try option `ImageLines[...,Method-> "Segmented"->True] `

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I tried that but the lines didn't line up with the image, there were either too many lines or many lines were missing.

Comment: `MorphologicalGraph@Thinning@Invert@i`?

Comment: Ah yes,`ColorNegate`, not `Invert`

Comment: Do you have the image in its original scale, in a non-lossy (non-JPEG) format?

Comment: Relation this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102262/21532

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
g = IndexGraph[
  MorphologicalGraph[
   Thinning[ColorNegate[Binarize[pic]], Method -> "MedialAxis"]]]
```

[image]

Then you can merge vertices that are close each other:

```
pts = GraphEmbedding[g];

Median[EuclideanDistance[pts[[#[[1]]]], pts[[#[[2]]]]] & /@ 
  EdgeList[g]]
```

> 13.0384

```
f = Nearest[Thread[pts -> Range[Length[pts]]]]

merge = Select[f[#, {All, 10}] & /@ pts, Length[#] > 1 &];
```

You can check the grouping of vertices:

```
HighlightGraph[g, merge, VertexSize -> 1]
```

[image]

and final graph:

final = Fold[VertexContract, g, merge]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

First, use the method of deleting the branch points developed in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129460/280) answer:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLhGVm.png"];

imb = Thinning[ColorNegate@Binarize@img];

edges = DeleteSmallComponents@MorphologicalTransform[imb, 
   If[#[[2, 2]] == 1 && Total[#, 2] == 3, 1, 0] &];

edgesLabeled = MorphologicalComponents[edges];
edgesLabeled // Colorize
```

> [image]

Second, extract the branch points (`nodes`) and separate them from the edges by making their labels sufficiently large, as I did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148103/280):

```
nodes = imb - edges;
threshold = 10^Ceiling[Log10[Max[edgesLabeled] + 1]];
nodesLabeled = MorphologicalComponents[nodes] * threshold;
nodesLabeled // Colorize
```

> [image]

```
edgesPlusNodesLabeled = edgesLabeled + nodesLabeled;
edgesPlusNodesLabeled // Colorize
```

> [image]

Now it is easy to reconstruct the graph:

```
neighbors = 
  ComponentMeasurements[edgesPlusNodesLabeled, 
   "Neighbors", #Label < threshold &];
coords = ComponentMeasurements[edgesPlusNodesLabeled, 
   "BoundingDiskCenter", #Label >= threshold &];

Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ neighbors[[All, 2]], 
 VertexCoordinates -> coords, VertexSize -> .2]
```

> [image: graph]

Overlay on the original image:

```
HighlightImage[img, {Thick, Line /@ neighbors[[All, 2]] /. coords, 
  Green, Translate[Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[2]], coords[[All, 2]]]}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Your answer and halmir's are both excellent! If I could accept two I would have but I chose the halmir's because it's simpler.

Comment: This is a particularly interesting question, and I asked a similar question for non-planar graphs. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261413/is-it-possible-to-extract-vertices-and-lines-from-this-image-of-nonplanar-graph